# How to migrate routes from .NET to ASP.NET Core? (Specific example)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on a migration from .NET and .NET Core and I am having difficulties with the routing configuration in startup.cs.

From the ASP.NET project, we had the following routing code:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Now, I am trying to find something that would simply replace this functionality. What I have been working on so far is the following:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "GHS", action = "RequestForm" });
        });
```

this works for a single controller and action but I am looking for something that would "RegisterAllAreas".

I have found the following article from Microsoft but was unable to find anything that specifically matched this. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html

Is there a way to map all the routes similar to how it was done in .NET code?

**Extra information:**

I think in the previous version, the url was generated from the View somehow because only the following urls work:

http://localhost:23046/contact-us.html

http://localhost:23046/ghs-request.html

**Update:**

I have just realized that my project has two files named "contact-us.html" and "ghs-request.html" and these html files has the connection to the javascript files. Therefore, I only need to connect my View forms to these html scripts.

Comment: I am trying to modify the question as I realize if it is a stupid question. Please let me know about my mistakes and I will try to modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        // areas
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "area",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        // default
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In .net 6 in the minimal Program.cs If you used UseMvc as given by selected answer you would get the warning:

`Warning    MVC1005 Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing. To continue using 'UseMvc', please set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside '<Main>$'.`

Using the .net minimal Program.cs in .net 6.
if `GHS` is your controller and `RequestForm` is your action.

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=GHS}/{action=RequestForm}/{id?}"
    defaults: new { controller = "GHS", action = "RequestForm" });
```

or more simplified should also work

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
    defaults: new { controller = "GHS", action = "RequestForm" });
```

or

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=GHS}/{action=RequestForm}/{id?}");
```